# PHP MySQL optimize speed with temporary table in specific example

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Suppose I have a table as shown underneath:

```
ID|Word
1 |Word1
1 |Word2
2 |Word4
6 |Word5
6 |Word6
```

For each word I know the position in the file such as:

```
ID|Position
1 |2
1 |16
1 |67
2 |3
2 |78
2 |89
...
6 |22
6 |62
```

When I search for exactly the phrase 'Word1 Word2' within a file, I would like to get back the ID's of the files where I have found this occurrence. To achieve this, I join both tables with Word1 and Word 2 with the same FilerID, which results in the underneath temporary table:

```
ID|Word |Position
1 |Word1|2
1 |Word1|16
1 |Word1|67
1 |Word2|3
1 |Word2|78
```

From this temporary table I would like to get back the following results:

```
ID|Word |Position
1 |Word1|2
1 |Word2|3
```

Since this is the only occurrence with the exact phrase 'Word1 Word2'. However, how can I achieve this with a 'fast performing` query. In this case each method is fast of course, however the tables I work with are over 1.000.000 rows easily since I have many files. So, I'm looking to the fastest solution. If somebody has another solution which is faster, please let me know!

Comment: Well... You definitely need to use a join.  You theoretically could use just a join, instead of creating the temp table. You would join your table to the same table -> `from tableX t1 join tableX t2`. The on clause would look something like this: `t1.position + 1 = t2.position and t1.word = "word1" and t2.word = "word2"`. Or instead of words you could use the word ids. That way you do not need to join in the word tables at all (although you would need to do a separate selects to find out the ids).

Comment: ummm yes ... `MATCH(some_tbl.field) AGAINST ('"Word1 Word2"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` on a FULLTEXT index ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @ViliamAboši, this is how I'm doing it right now, but the queries are way to slow. (20 seconds at fastest execution)

Comment: @cmorrissey, I can't do that because the words are in a specific row. I have no FULLTEXT columns, since each word is stored separately

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  20 seconds smells like you don't have the right `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: Do you have free flowing text in some other table?  _That_ is where you need `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren that is weird it is slow. I've got tables with over two milion rows and it performs quite ok. Do you have the position indexed? Otherwise, if the temp table has a better performance try joining the temp table on itself. I don't see a way how you could achieve your result without it. Your table creates and the actual selects you are using would be of great help in improving the performance.

Comment: Yes both the positions and id's are indexed.